# Keep track of clicks on different buttons using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create a form with about ten candidates. There is a "vote for me" button underneath each candidate's name and description.

What I want to do is have a user click the button, have that increment the vote for that candidate, and then redirect the user to a success page.

Obviously the votes can't change on page refresh or if the user changes. However since I am using Wordpress posts/pages to display this form, I can't really use PHP in the page itself. I'm sort of confined to using JS in the header file.

I don't really care if the solution to this is kind of hacked together -- it doesn't have to be elegant. The other complication is that only we should be able to view the values. Any solutions would be very much appreciated.

Here is the code for a single button on the form --

```
 <button onclick="buttonClick()" id="button1">
 <img alt="" src="http://.../wp-content/uploads/2014/01/vote.png" />
 </button>
```

And the script is:

```
<script>
var i = 0;
function buttonClick() {
    document.getElementById('inc').value = ++i;
    document.location.href='http://.../thanks-voting';
}
</script>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: The question is, how do I do this. So far I've got the button incrementing a value on the page and redirecting -- but how do I keep incrementing the values with the limitations explained above?

Comment: if you use modern browsers you can store your data into the localStorage.

Comment: Any chance you could demonstrate what that syntax would look like in this case?